# SQLite table row not deleting when delete button pressed, android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to delete a row from a table in **SQLite** for the first time, I thought I'd followed a tutorial and adapted it to my app but I've messed up the syntax somewhere.

Here is the code from `DatabaseHelper.java`

```
public void deleteRow (String subject) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("delete from " + TABLE_NAME +" where " + COL_2 + "=" + subject);
}
```

And the code that calls it from SubjectActivity.java:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view.getId()==R.id.deleteSubject) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String subject = extras.getString("subject");
        myDb.deleteRow(subject);
    }
}
```

The row should be deleted when a delete button is pressed in the subject activity, but when I do press the button, the app force closes. What am I missing in the syntax?

Comment: I don't know, my emulators have stopped working in the last couple of days and I haven't been able to fix them yet. I've been running things on my phone, and all I know is that the app force closes when I click the delete button.

Comment: Check your logcat for fatal error. And post it.

Comment: May be no record available that satisfy the condition you are passing with delete query

Comment: what is myDb...?

Comment: @Omi, sorry: myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what your current raw query being passed to SQLite looks like:

```
delete from TABLE_NAME where COL_2 = some_subject
```

In other words, you are comparing `COL_2` against `some_subject`, which SQLite will interpret as a column, but not as a string literal.  Here is the query you intended to run:

```
delete from TABLE_NAME where COL_2 = 'some_subject'
```

The best fix here is to use prepared statements, where the query has a positional parameter (`?`) for the subject string.  The statement will automatically take care of escaping the string on your behalf.

```
public void deleteRow (String subject) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String sql = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL_2 + " = ?";
    SQLiteStatement statement = db.compileStatement(sql);
    statement.bindString(1, subject);

    int numRowsDeleted = statement.executeUpdateDelete();
    // you might want to check the number of records which were actually deleted
}
```

Note that it is not very typical to make the table and column names variable for a given statement.  Instead, you would usually see these being hard coded.  The reason for this is that it is unlikely that you would want to run the same statement on a different table, or the same table but with different columns.

Comment: Ok, so the SQLite isn't seeing my subject variable as the string in the row I want deleted but rather as the name of the collumn itself? Thanks for the response, would that code go inside my deleterow() function? I'm just having a little trouble seeing what the bindString and executeUpdateDelete functions do, sorry.

Comment: @Emma This is just a minor refactor to your `deleteRow()` method, q.v. my updated answer.

Comment: You do not need a prepared statement; `db.delete()` supports parameters, too.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for all your help @Tim Biegeleisen, and explaining why my code didn't work instead of just correcting it. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

check below code

```
public void deleteRow (String subject) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME , COL_2 + "=" + subject, null);
}
```